# Can you use a for loop to pop each value in a stack until there is only one left?

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, stack, push

I have an array with six values in it {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}.
I have been able to successfully push the values into a stack using a for loop. I am supposed to also write a for loop and pop each value from the stack until there is only one left. I can't find an example of it anywhere. Help, please?

```
int[] numbers = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
Stack<int> myStack = new Stack<int>();

for (int i = 0; i <numbers.Length; i++)
{
    mystack.Push(numbers[i]);
}

foreach(int item in myStack)
{
    Console.Write(item + ", ");
}
```

This prints the pushed values in the array. We have been using the other properties such as Peek and Count with stack as well. I don't have an issue with those. I don't have an issue using Pop for a single value either.

```
Console.WriteLine("The value popped from the stack is: {0} ", myStack.Pop());
```

My issue is trying to use a for loop to pop each item from the stack one by one. My brain isn't translating this well at all. I have looked for examples. I have not been able to find one using a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

A while loop may be better in this case. I would approach it like this:

```
while (myStack.Count > 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The value popped from the stack is: {0} ", myStack.Pop());
}
```

Comment: My professor specifically said for loop. I agree with you, I think a while loop is better in this case. Thank you for taking time out to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code.

```
int count = myStack.Count;
for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The value popped from the stack is: {0} ", myStack.Pop());
}
```

You can also use a while loop in place of for loop.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. It helps having an example!

Comment: @jamiegale21 please accept the answer, if it has really helped you

Answer (score 0):

```
// check stack count 
while (myStack.Count > 1)
{
    // console
    Console.WriteLine($@"POP VALUE: {myStack.Pop()}");
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = myStack.Count; i > 0; i--)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"The value popped from the stack is: {myStack.Pop()}");
    }
```

To use a for loop with a stack you want to use it in a descending manner, while initializing the loop variable to the count in the stack. If you use the stack length as the conditional it will check against the current count every time and stop prematurely